# PHPMailer and multiples destination addresses issue

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Im using phpmailer to send emails and i check that when i add some addresses and just one of them is an invalid address (not exists) E.G. "asdfasfasf@asdfasdfsfsfs.commm" and send the email i see that the email was sent (to correct addresses) and i have no idea how to check if one of the adresses is wrong to be able to log that issue before sending the email.

The code to send and add addresses is this:

```
foreach($options['emails'] as $email){
      $mmail->AddAddress($email[0], $email[1]);
}

if (!$mmail->Send()) {
    echo "error";
}else {
     echo "sent";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`filter_var`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to validate the syntax:

```
if (filter_var($email[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // email address is considered valid
```

Note that there are ways to connect to the recipients SMTP server and ask if the email actually exists (see https://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/ for example) however many email servers won't honor these queries anymore, due to spammer abuse.

Comment: i mean wrong address as an email address that doesn´t exists, not a bad formatted address. sorry for my bad explanation...

Comment: There is no foolproof way to see if an email address actually exists. There used to be (SMTP queries) but spammers abused it. Some folks will at least do an MX lookup on the domain name to see if that can be verified.

Comment: The only way truly to know if an email is valid, is to send an email and have the recipient click a link acknowledging receipt.